# Is it possible to develop a login system after I have already created my User's table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a pretty novice developer, and I recently made a Rails app that allows my roommate and I to keep track of our apartment stuff.

I have created a User's table in my DB, and now I want to implement a sign-up/sign-on feature so we each have logins.

Looking at this [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/simple-login/0.1.8) for the simple_login gem it looks like this will create a Users table for me - it sounds like this can be a problem. Any way to add a sign-on feature to an already existing User's table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow and to Rails.

Adding a login system to an already defined `users` table is certainly possible.

The [simple_login](https://rubygems.org/gems/simple-login) gem you mentioned seems to be a "batteries included" solution that lacks flexibility, which is the reason why it tries to create everything for you and it wouldn't work with your already created `users` table. Even ignoring that, it looks like it has less than 20,000 downloads and it hasn't been updated since 2012. This means that it hasn't really proved itself in the wild (which is important for authentication), and that it's highly unlikely that it will work smoothly with recent versions of Ruby on Rails. I would recommend to not use it.

Ruby on Rails provides some built in basic functionality to support authentication, with the [`has_secure_password`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password) ActiveRecord helper. It still requires you to implement the HTTP request and view template plumbing to present a log in screen.

Alternatively, you can still use a more fully-featured gem:

[devise](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise) is probably the most widely used authentication management gem for Ruby on Rails. It automates almost everything, and the GitHub repo contains a wealth of documentation and examples.

[sorcery](https://rubygems.org/gems/sorcery) is another popular choice that has been around for ages. It's more low-touch and less opinionated than devise, as it provides the authentication building blocks and expects you to put them together.